# how to correctly use string literal in Python - line with both " and { and use format replace

Tags: python, string

I have the following command I need to send to a device console:

```
abcd '{ "aa" : "bb" ,"cc" : "{}", "ff": {"ee" : "{}", "dynamic_multicast_rate" : "{}" }}'
```

I want to replace only `{}` using `format(var1, var2, var3)`
I was not able to normally achieve it.

Comment: if you want to build a json string, i'd recommend looking into the `json` module. You can then just turn a dict into a string, `json.dumps({"aa": "bb", "cc": var1})` etc

Comment: Try working with a dictionary instead of a string, you can also use an f-string but you have to escape the curly braces `{` and `}` with a `\ ` like: `abcd = f'\{ "aa" : "bb" ,"cc" : "{var1}", "ff": \{"ee" : "{var2}", "dynamic_multicast_rate" : "{var3}" \}\}'` but that's messy